# how to for loop ndarray by block

Tags: numpy-ndarray

i want to do mean filtering on a ndarray, just like scipy.signal.medfilt

```
x = np.arange(1, 26).reshape((5, 5))
y = np.copy(x)

kernel_size = 3
radius = kernel_size // 2
for index, val in np.ndenumerate(x):
    top = 0 if index[0] < radius else index[0] - radius
    bottom = x.shape[0] if index[0] + radius >= x.shape[0] \
        else index[0] + radius + 1
    left = 0 if index[1] < radius else index[1] - radius
    right = x.shape[1] if index[1] + radius >= x.shape[1]\
        else index[1] + radius + 1

    print(f"{x[top:bottom, left:right]}")

    y[index] = x[top:bottom, left:right].mean()
```

the iteration can be vectorized? or some more efficient code?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html ?

Comment: if I want to calculate the mean except the center element? Or I want to calculate the mean of some axis, for example 0 or 1?

Comment: then use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.convolve

Comment: Is there a function iterate ndarray by block and let me pass a lambda or function to do some calculation?

Comment: Thank you very much! Inspired by you, I found scipy.ndimage.generic_filter, that is I wanted!Thank you again!